# Overwriting CSS : Display none property with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, settimeout

For an element defined as display:none in css I am trying to run a function which tries to display the element using .show(), code below:

**CSS**

```
.element {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="element">Some content here</div>
<div class="element">Some content here</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var c = $('.element');

c.each(function () {
  c.css({
    'left': dleft + 'px'
  });

  c.css({
    'top': dtop + 'px'
  });

  c.setTimeout(function () {
    c.show(1000);
  }, sduration);
```

All the variables are getting populated I have checked by alerting all of them and given them default values as well, but somehow the element is not being shown after the timeout.

Comment: You can't use setTimeout like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be two problems in the code you have written. you have not closed the .each() loop .. Also setTimeout is a global function.. .. Check this

```
    var dleft = 40;
var dtop = 40;
var sduration = 1000;
var c = $('.element');

c.each(function() {
    c.css({
        'left': dleft + 'px',
        'top': dtop + 'px'
    });
});
setTimeout(function() {
    c.show(1000);
}, sduration);​
```

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/MHvjA/)

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` is a global function.

```
var c = $('.element');

c.each(function () {
  c.css({ 'left': dleft + 'px', 'top': dtop + 'px' });

  setTimeout(function () {
    c.show(1000);
  }, sduration);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/S7nw3/

Answer (score 0):

If you need to delay when the elements are being shown, you can also make use of the jQuery [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) function.

```
c.each(function() {
    c.css({
        'left': dleft + 'px',
        'top': dtop + 'px'
    });
});

c.delay(1000).show();
```

Comment: if you're trying to animate the showing of the element, you pass that into the .show() method itself, so instead of the delay, you can use .show('slow')

Comment: Thanks, but i got that by using .animate and the callback using complete parameter....